# Laravel and shared hosting CURL not working

Tags: php, laravel, curl, hosting

I am deploying my Laravel application to shared hosting from Godaddy for testing purposes only (so that I can share it in a domain) for production I will be using a better solution.

In my localhost, everything works fine, but in hosting CURL is not working. Actually, this CURL

```
function setUrl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, public_path().'/cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, public_path().'/cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

This does not work. When I check my `cookies.txt` file in the hosting it is always empty, actually I tried moving it to public, another folder and everywhere, but it does not get edited, it is always empty. It worked fine in my localhost, but for some reason it doesn't want to work in hosting.

Does anyone have some idea to tackle this issue?

This I my curinfo if it helps

```
"content_type" => null
  "http_code" => 0
  "header_size" => 0
  "request_size" => 0
  "filetime" => -1
  "ssl_verify_result" => 0
  "redirect_count" => 0
  "total_time" => 0.200232
  "namelookup_time" => 4.8E-5
  "connect_time" => 0.0
  "pretransfer_time" => 0.0
  "size_upload" => 0.0
  "size_download" => 0.0
  "speed_download" => 0.0
  "speed_upload" => 0.0
  "download_content_length" => -1.0
  "upload_content_length" => -1.0
  "starttransfer_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_url" => ""
  "primary_ip" => ""
  "certinfo" => []
  "primary_port" => 0
  "local_ip" => ""
  "local_port" => 0
]
```

Comment: Is curl enabled on the server?

Comment: @buzzfizz it's enabled by default, I have checked it and it does recognize curl commands

Comment: `echo phpinfo();` in a separate file and check whether curl is enabled on a server or not. If not then contact the support team.

Comment: Any reason why are you using curl instead of php's own file writing?

Comment: Either the text file has insufficient permission or the public_path() returns a different path.

Comment: I tried both actually, permission is set to 777, public_path() returns the public folder, because it works for setting the image path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely, you're being firewall-blocked by GoDaddy. i've seen same shit countless times on shared webhosts. you should probably invest in a VPS instead (they're like $3.5/month on ramnode..), but you're also doing some mistakes, namely you ignore any errors given by curl_setopt, it returns bool(false) on failure, which your code completely ignores. try using this instead:

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' .  curl_errno ($ch) .' curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
```

however, when debugging curl, you should always enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and get the verbose log, it's usually super useful when debugging curl code, like

```
function setUrl($url) {
    $debugfileh=tmpfile();
    $ch = curl_init();
    try{
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $debugfileh);
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, public_path().'/cookies/cookies.txt');
    ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, public_path().'/cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    return $buffer;
    }finally{
    var_dump('curl verbose log:',file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($debugfileh)['uri']));
    fclose($debugfileh);
    curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```